# How is the zeroth term of the Minkowski force derived?

Tags: special-relativity, forces, vectors

I'm working through T.M. Helliwell's Special Relativity on my own, and one of the questions asks to show that the Minkowski force $K_\mu=dp_\mu/d\tau$ can be written $$K_\mu=\left(\gamma\frac{\mathbf{v\cdot F}}{c}, \gamma F_x, \gamma F_y, \gamma F_z\right).$$

The first second and third term seem trivial, and by inspection it seems that $dE/d\tau=\gamma \mathbf{v\cdot F}$. I've tried using the relations $E=\gamma mc^2$ and $E^2=(pc)^2 + (mc^2)^2$, but I can't get the appropriate form starting from either of those. How can I show that $dE/d\tau=\gamma\mathbf{v\cdot F}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just the following (setting $c = 1$):
$$\frac{dE}{d\tau} = \frac{dE}{dt} \frac{dt}{d\tau} = (\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{F})\, \gamma.$$

---

I guess you might also want to ask, why is $dE/dt = \mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{F}$ in special relativity? Well, if you start with
$$E^2 = p^2 + m^2$$
and take the time derivative of both sides, you have
$$E \, \frac{dE}{dt} = \mathbf{p} \cdot \frac{d\mathbf{p}}{dt}.$$
The second term on the right is $\mathbf{F}$, by definition. And 
$$\frac{\mathbf{p}}{E} = \frac{\gamma m \mathbf{v}}{\gamma m} = \mathbf{v}$$
by the definitions of relativistic momentum and energy. So solving for $dE/dt$ gives $\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{F}$.

Answer (score 0):

$K_{\mu}v^{\mu}$ is a Lorentz invariant. Evaluating it with a (+---) signature in the proper frame where $\textbf v = (c,0)$: 
$$K_{\mu}v^{\mu} = \gamma\frac{d}{dt}(E/c,\,\gamma\textbf{p})\cdot\gamma(c,\textbf{v})=\frac{d}{d\tau}(mc,\,\textbf{p})\cdot(c,0) = c^2\frac{dm}{d\tau}$$

If the force is (rest) mass preserving, $dm/d\tau$=0:

$$K_{\mu}v^{\mu} = \gamma^2\left( \frac{dE}{dt} - \textbf{v}\cdot\frac{d}{dt}\gamma\textbf{p}\right) = 0,\quad \Rightarrow \frac{dE}{dt} = \textbf{v}\cdot\textbf{F}$$

Therefore:
$$
K_\mu=\gamma\left(\frac{1}{c}\frac{dE}{dt}, F_x, F_y, F_z\right)=
\gamma\left(\frac{\mathbf{v\cdot F}}{c}, F_x, F_y, F_z\right)
$$